# Can someone explain this syntax for the .appendTo() method?

Tags: jquery, syntax

I setting up data-tables for the first time and came across this code which works great. It places the buttons container nicely into the datatables table.

That said, I am having a hard time understanding how this works given the syntax. I did take a look at the .appendTo() documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), but it doesn't fully explain the syntax below.

`api.buttons().container().appendTo( '#' + api.table().container().id + ' .col-sm-12:eq(0)' );`

Specifically, I don't understand the `target` content.

`#` - There is no id property assigned to the element that it is appending to.

What is `api.table().container().id` doing there?

And finally, it is locating the buttons container into the element with the `.col-sm-12` classes, but what is `eq(0)`??

I'd appreciate any input. Thanks!!

Comment: The documentation mentions that `appendTo` accepts a [selector](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Selector), so read the [Selectors API docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser to find out what `'#' + api.table().container().id + ' .col-sm-12:eq(0)'` evaluates to.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the correct direction - in some ways that was more helpful than just explaining. I can see what I missed. Is there a way to up-vote your response? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer edited for better clarity:

The `.appendTo()` method takes in a selector which it will append to - in this case, the buttons are appended to the element matching the selector.

Since there are several matches in the document the `:eq(0)` part is jQuery that gets the first match only since there are several matches of that selector and we don't want it appended at every match.